# GAE datastore group entity pro and cons

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore, ancestor

I am Modelling a database under GAE dealing with  processing learners assessment. So let's say I have  this:

```
class Assesment(db.Model):

    usrId= db.StringProperty(required=True)
    subjectID= db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=set(["math", "Eng", "art"]))
    when= db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add)
    score= db.IntegerProperty()
    solved= db.BooleanProperty()
```

I've two other modules, one for **Learners** properties, such as name, address, email and another one for **Subject** information such name, hints, video_url ..etc
I know that I have to forget anything related to classic DBMS modelling.

Should I keep all modules (**Assessment**, **Learners** and **Subjects** )in the same group entity and how 1 writing per second  will affect the performance of the website once implemented.
and if not, how much properties can my assessment  module can handle without shrinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, there are no reasons to keep all of your models in the same entity group. You create a major performance bottleneck without any benefits.

A single entity group (parent-child relationship) is necessary when a strong consistency or transactions are required, which is a relatively rare use case. Sometimes, a parent-child entity relationship maybe used for convenience of retrieving data, but you have to weigh carefully each use case.

I am not sure what you mean by "shrinking", but if you are concerned about the performance it should not degrade noticeably unless you have hundreds of properties, in which case it's a good idea to separate frequently updated properties from rarely updated properties into different entities.